# How do I Invert a Guard in GDX-AI?

Tags: libgdx, ai, behavior-tree

I am trying to define an AI behavior where if a conditional (`MyCondition`) is false, execute the task. I know I can do this as follows:

```
import myCondition?:"tech.otter.something.MyCondition"
import otherTask:"tech.otter.something.OtherTask"

root
  selector
    myCondition? # i.e. if !myCondition then otherTask
    otherTask
```

Now I'd like to use the snazzy guard syntax like so:

```
root
  (myCondition?) otherTask
```

The problem is that I really need otherTask to fire when the guard (myCondition?) is *false*. Is there a way to do this shy of defining a "MyInvertedCondition" task?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using decorators which can be read about [here](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Behavior-Trees#decorator).
I believe the syntax would be like this: `(invert MyCondition)`.

If that doesn't work you can always use a subtree as your guard. The syntax would then be like this:

```
subtree name:"Invertedguard"
    invert MyCondition?

($Invertedguard)
```